# animate polygons in series of kml/geojson/shp

Tags: kml, geojson, animation, concave-hull

I have a series of KML files (though they could easily be converted to geoJSON, SHP, or anything else that `ogr2ogr` can handle), each file containing a set of polygons that correspond to the alpha shape (concave hull) of my movements for that day. I'd like to animate the polygons so that I can see how my personal alpha shape changes over time. Is there a particularly straightforward way to do this? I've looked at what Google Earth can offer but I can't help but think there's an easier way.

Comment: KML is a natural choice for spatio-temporal presentation as it supports embedded representation of time explicitly associated with spatial features. When you say that you've "looked at what Google Earth can offer," have you looked at the [time and animation support in KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/time)? For your current application, the goal would be to merge the multiple, static KML files you currently have into one KML file with multiple TimeStamp-ed Placemarks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done a similar thing using OpenLayers.  My use case was actually points not polygons but the principle is the same. I stored the data in a PostGIS back-end and used a simple Python script to update the PostGIS store on a periodic basis (every 10 miliseconds in my case).  I then used Geoserver to server the PostGIS layer as a WFS service. If you then use [OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Refresh-js.html) in your webpage to update your WFS layer, you can achieve nice animation of changing geographic features.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick and dirty example about the animation of polygons using [**simplekml**](http://code.google.com/p/simplekml/):

```
import simplekml
kml = simplekml.Kml()

pol = kml.newpolygon(name='Concave hull 1')
pol.outerboundaryis = [(18.333868,-34.038274), (18.370618,-34.034421),
    (18.350616,-34.051677),(18.333868,-34.038274)]
pol.style.linestyle.color = simplekml.Color.green
pol.style.linestyle.width = 5
pol.style.polystyle.color = simplekml.Color.changealphaint(100, simplekml.Color.green)
pol.timespan.begin = "2013-10-13T08:00:00Z"
pol.timespan.end = "2013-10-13T20:00:00Z"

pol = kml.newpolygon(name='Concave hull 2')
pol.outerboundaryis = [(18.347171,-34.040177), (18.355741,-34.039730),
    (18.350467,-34.048388),(18.347171,-34.040177)]
pol.style.linestyle.color = simplekml.Color.red
pol.style.linestyle.width = 5
pol.style.polystyle.color = simplekml.Color.changealphaint(100, simplekml.Color.red)
pol.timespan.begin = "2013-10-14T08:00:00Z"
pol.timespan.end = "2013-10-14T20:00:00Z"

kml.save("animated_polygons.kml")
```