# How to create a KML that supports animated ground overlays?

Tags: gdal, kml, animation

I have 12 images that represent weather conditions at day 1 through day 12. I am using gdal2tiles to produce map tiles from each of these images. gdal2tiles also produces a KML file that can be used in Google Earth to display the tiles.

However, I want to create an animated layer out of all 12 images.
Google Earth seems to support animation in KML files (see https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/time#example2). Are there any tools to create an animated ground overlay KML file such as this? Is gdal2tiles capable of it?

Thanks a lot.
- Mike

Comment: My best suggestion would be to follow this commenter's advice: "http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72550/animate-polygons-in-series-of-kml-geojson-shp?rq=1" and attempt "to merge the multiple, static KML files you currently have into one KML file with multiple TimeStamp-ed Placemarks". As gdal2tiles produces the KML file, it would appear that that would be the tool to use. Sorry I can't offer much more than this. Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A wonderful tool to create an animated ground overlays KML file is [**simplekml**](http://code.google.com/p/simplekml/), *"a python package which enables you to generate KML with as little effort as possible."*

The following is a quick and dirty reproduction of the [TimeSpan Example](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/time#example2) you mentioned before using simplekml:

```
import simplekml
kml = simplekml.Kml()

ground1 = kml.newgroundoverlay(name='Blue Marble - Jan')
ground1.icon.href = 'http://mw1.google.com/mw-earth-vectordb/kml-samples/bmng12/files/BMNG-Jan.jpg'
ground1.gxlatlonquad.coords = [(-180,-90),(180,-90),(180,90),(-180,90)]
ground1.timespan.begin = "2004-01-01"
ground1.timespan.end = "2004-01-31"

ground2 = kml.newgroundoverlay(name='Blue Marble - Feb')
ground2.icon.href = 'http://mw1.google.com/mw-earth-vectordb/kml-samples/bmng12/files/BMNG-Feb.jpg'
ground2.gxlatlonquad.coords = [(-180,-90),(180,-90),(180,90),(-180,90)]
ground2.timespan.begin = "2004-02-01"
ground2.timespan.end = "2004-02-29"

ground3 = kml.newgroundoverlay(name='Blue Marble - Mar')
ground3.icon.href = 'http://mw1.google.com/mw-earth-vectordb/kml-samples/bmng12/files/BMNG-Mar.jpg'
ground3.gxlatlonquad.coords = [(-180,-90),(180,-90),(180,90),(-180,90)]
ground3.timespan.begin = "2004-03-01"
ground3.timespan.end = "2004-03-31"

# ...and so on with the other months

kml.save("TimeSpan_Example_simplekml.kml")
```